# How can we apply here the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have shown that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\displaystyle{f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ subject to $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=1}$ has at $\left (-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, \ldots , -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\right)$ a minimum and at the point $\left (\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, \ldots , \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\right)$ there is a maximum.

How can we verify that result using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: You mean $\pm(\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\dots,\frac{1}{\sqrt n})$ ? Because your two points don't belong to the sphere $\sum x_i^2=1$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right!! Thank you!! @NicolasFRANCOIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right|^2=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i \times 1)\right|^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)\times n=n$$
with equality holds if and only if
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=k(1,\ldots,1)$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{R}.$ Given the restriction, you  can find the $k$.

**Remark:** I don't think your maximum and minimum points satisfy the constraint.

Comment: About the remark: Yes you're right!! About the first part: How did you get the iff condition that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=k(1,\ldots,1)$ ?

Comment: This is the “equality part” of Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: From the inequality above we get $$-\sqrt{n}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\leq \sqrt{n}$$ or not? That means that we know the minimum and maximum value of the function and we have to find the point where the function gets these values, or not?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Do we have to derive from that that $x$ is $\pm \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \ldots , \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ or do we have to substitute these points and see that the two equalities are then satisfied?

Comment: You have to derive that, as substituting the points into the function only prove that $\pm(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ is two of the solutions to the optimization problem, but not the ONLY solutions to the problem.

Comment: Ah ok! I see!! But I haven't really understood how we can derive that. Could you explain this further to me?

Comment: Alright. You got the constraint $\sum x_i^2=1$, and in the case of equality, $(x_1,...,x_n)=k(1,...,1)$, so what you do is to substitute it into the constraint. Then you will get $nk^2=1$, which gives you $k=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: I am still confused about how we get that $(x_1, \ldots , x_n)=k(1, \ldots , 1)$.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz: $|u \bullet v| \leq |u||v|$ with equality iff $u=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you so much!! :-)